# redefinition of typedef errors in unofficial opengl sdk

Tags: opengl, codeblocks, redefinition

using the arcsynthesis opengl tutorial and I'm trying to build the unofficial sdk that the examples use, per the instructions here: http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/pg_build.html#page_build_libs . (I'm using code::blocks and the gnu gcc compiler, and 0.4.0 of the unofficial sdk) It's not working, I get this error:

> `C:\libs\c\glsdk_0.4.0\glload\source\wgll_ext_base.h|29|error: redefinition of typedef 'GLenum'|`
>
> `C:\libs\c\glsdk_0.4.0\glload\source\gll_gl_ext_base.h|27|note: previous declaration of 'GLenum' was here|`

repeated several times for other sybmols, including GLBoolean, GLBitField, etc. since I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to fix this by actually modifying the sdk I'm assuming it's a build/linker muckup on my part, but I'm only using the workspace that premake4 generated, not rolling my own or anything.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> arcsynthesis opengl tutorial and I'm trying to build the unofficial sdk that the examples use, per the instructions here: http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/pg_build.html#page_build_libs .

The Tutorial distribution comes *with* the SDK; it's in the folder called `glsdk`. You aren't supposed to download the SDK from the SDK site. The [Tutorial build instruction explain how to build it](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Building%20the%20Tutorials.html).

Also, the 0.4.0 version is somewhat old; there was a build problem with Code::Blocks (and probably other builds). The most recent release is 0.4.2, which should work.

Comment: that worked perfectly. thanks. I dont know how I ended up with a slightly out of date version to begin with.

Comment: yarlesp - its customary to upvote a person who helps you solves your issue ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Follow the premake instructions for vs2010
2. In Code::Blocks, go to file-->import project-->Microsoft Visual Studio Solution
3. Import openglsdk.sln from the directory where you placed the sdk files

Now the sdk will be available as a workspace in Code::Blocks.  As of this post, the Unofficial OpenGL SDK is version 0.50.  I answered this with step by step directions because I couldn't find any for Code::Blocks, and some people just beginning to learn OpenGL may need a little guidance.